# Android: keep screen on from widget

Tags: android

I have a home screen widget and I want to add "keep screen on" functionality. So how do I set the flag "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON" from within an AppWidgetProvider.onReceive method?

From within an activity you would do a

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

but I only have a Context object at hand...

Comment: can i ask why? Unlike activities which a user can simply leave, a widget is more permanent and will cost the users batteries life to die if they don't turn it off manually. That of course translates to bad reviews in the market.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's a project to connect your phone wirelessly to adb. The widget is a simple button to switch the connection on and off. Like plugging in the cable and pulling it out.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I set the flag "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON" from within an AppWidgetProvider.onReceive method?

You can't, sorry. `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` is for use by activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

android.provider.Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),  android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, "-1");